# How Can I add Shake Gesture in Cocos2d CCLayer?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, gesture, shake

I've tried using [shake Gesture Recognition wrapper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/12216) to detect the shake gesture. 
I've also tried to implement the code suggested in the [Geeky Lemon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kIEOW_7dIw).
But I am unable to handle the shake gesture. Is there any way to get the shake gesture recognized?

Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

The code is done by the help of the shake Gesture Recognition wrapper demo.

in the init method

```
ShakeDispatcher * dispatcher = [ShakeDispatcher sharedInstance];
[dispatcher addShakeListener:self];    
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view] addGestureRecognizer:dispatcher];

-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake ){      
        NSLog(@"Shake detected");   
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your gesture recogniser the normal way and then add it like so

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:shakeGesture];
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use `ShakeEnabledUIWindow` instead of `UIWindow`. In your `AppDelegate` you need to import the file and you need to create instance for that window, like

```
#import "ShakeEnabledUIWindow.h"
```

Then create instance for `ShakeEnabledUIWindow`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ShakeEnabledUIWindow *window;
```

Now it'll work. Try these [link](http://www.softvelopment.com/index.php/blogs/2010/03/19/3-adding-shake-recongnition-to-cocos2d-iphone-library-) for implementing your `Shake Gesture`.